# Play music and pause music at specific time. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, audio, settimeout, setinterval

I want to play music all day but I want auto pause in specific time like 
play 24 hours.
and stop at 05:30 ( for 30 min then play )
and again stop at 08:30 ( for 30 min then play )

I have tried the below code it works but there is error like when music re play after finish stop time the sound interrupt then back normal

```js
<script>
var audio = new Audio('2.mp3');
audio.play();

function updateTime(){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  if ((hours == 17 && minutes == 17 ) && !audio.paused) {
     audio.pause();
     setTimeout(function() { audio.play();}, 10000);
             
}
}

setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: You want the music to restart from the beginning, is that the problem?

Comment: @MarioZ  no .. i want to pause the music at specific time and then play after some minutes after paused